# Implement "Press any key to close" in neovim terminal buffer

Tags: vimscript, neovim, terminal

When running shell commands in a terminal buffer I often just want to examine the output, and then close the buffer. Let's say I call `:term ls`. How would I implement a simple "Press any key to close" which wipes out the terminal buffer on pressing any key?

Comment: Instead of using `:terminal`, how do you feel about `:!` or `:r!? e.g. `:!ls` or `:r! ls`

Comment: Good point. I guess I like the fact that `:term` opens a new buffer and thus fills the entire window, whereas the output of `:!` is only printed in, what?, a quickfix window? Anyway, I prefer the look of whatever `:term` does.